# determine which child element was clicked by parent event handler

Tags: jquery

two click handling functions

```
$('#current_options').on('click', 'td', function(){
    $('#product_options_list tbody').css('display', 'none');
    $('.sub_options tbody').css('display', '');
    var my_id = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
    $('#product_options_list thead').css('display', '');
    $('#product_options_list tbody#'+my_id).css('display', '');
});

$('#current_options').on('click', '.icon-minus-sign', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var rem_id = $(this).parent().find('input').val();

    //remove corresponding option values
    $('#product_options_list tbody#'+rem_id).remove();

    //either highlight next options values or hide table header if no other values present          
    $('#product_options_list thead').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();


});
```

html

```
<table id="current_options" class="table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            Size<i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>
         </td>
```

basically, I want to stop the click handler on the td from firing if the click handler on the i inside the td is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for jQuery's [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$('#current_options').on('click', '.icon-minus-sign', function(e){
    ..
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `stopPropagation` like this:

```
$('#current_options').on('click', '.icon-minus-sign', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); //this stops the event from moving up the parents

    var rem_id = $(this).parent().find('input').val();

    //remove corresponding option values
    $('#product_options_list tbody#'+rem_id).remove();

    //either highlight next options values or hide table header if no other values present          
    $('#product_options_list thead').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();


});
```

If you're using `.on()` or `.delegate()` then just do a `return false;` right at the end of your `function`

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/